# Is it ok to pull huge amount of data locally into redux store?

Tags: reactjs, redux

So I'm currently building an app in react using redux as state management.

So is it wise to pull huge amount of data from backend api into redux store and let the app use the locally stored data?

The pro is it does save lots of api request specially for data that is used in multiple parts of the application, but I have no idea what are the consequences.

Ex. I pull 20k amount of db records into a redux store state, would that result in lag or poor performance into the client's browser?

Any help is appreciated
Thanks

Comment: 20k records will likely use a lot of memory. You probably should look into using redux as a cache so that you don't have to load all those records at the same time.

Comment: "for data that is used in multiple parts of the application" This is what redux is designed to handle. You can make an API request once and store the response in redux so that the application can use it anywhere.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Yeah, but like ex. that reusable data is 20k amount (thinking in worst case here) you think storing that 20k is still not a good idea?

Comment: Storing 20k records in redux will consume a non-trivial amount of memory. First, I suggest measuring how much memory it uses. Unless you need to show them all on a single page, then you probably don't want to fetch them all. You can use some kind of caching scheme to store only the records needed.